# Object Hierarchy in QTP doesnt show Browser Object and starts with Page Hierarchy.Object Doesn't get added

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

While getting the Object Properties of Menu in an application QTP doesn't show Browser Hierarchy but instead starts from Page level. I have navigated till below. After clicking on web element a menu appears but in Object spy that menu has its own page but no browser level hierarchy.

```
Browser().Page().Frame().Weblement().Click
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: ScreenShot :  screencast.com/t/YvTjEHRbE1

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: The application is compatible with IE8

Comment: Are you actually using IE or is this some kind of browser control?

Comment: @Motti I am actually using IE. No Smoke kind of browser control

Comment: Doesn't Page().WebElement work though?  Although, I do not think its a good approach but If my memory serves right, you can skip Browser even if the object spy shows it in the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Anshoo. didn't know it works that way also. will try and update accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Please share the application name, which you are testing.
Also, point to remember

**Issue # 1**

- UFT 12.01 Supports IE10,IE11.
- UFT 11 Supports IE8
- UFT 11.5 supports IE8,IE9 with patch installed

**Issue# 2**

When you are performing the Object spy, try moving on the side of menu bar.
Sometimes This list can be identified by the below code.

```
Browser(objBrowser).Page(objPage).WebDropDownMenu.select <Name>
```

Try this i guess this would solve your issue.

Remember, You never no when you will find the new object from Object spy, which might not have seen it earlier.

Comment: Sunil Khuwal:Thanks for the reply.
 
Cant share  the Application Name. Client will not allow to.

I am using UFT 12.01 and it supports IE8. I have automated many application in IE8 with 12.01

I have tried to use object spy but cant seem to add the object to Object repository. 

Please let me know if there is any other way.

Comment: Please use the compatibility mode..as far as i understand UFT12 doesn't support IE8...it will support Ie9or higher..